# Vector bundle and inverse image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:Z\to X$ be an immersion of schemes. Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$(coherent and locally free of finite type and say constant rank $n$).

Suppose that $O_X$ is not necessarily coherent.
It seems that the $O_Z$-Module $f^*E$ need not to be a vector bundle. Which kind of conditions on $f$ could be added to ensure $f^*E$ to be a vector bundle?

(I know that locally free of finite type means (flat+of finite presentation), so maybe a question related is when does a pull-back of a flat $O_X$-Module flat?)

Comment: I see absolutely no reason to assume that a "vector bundle" should correspond to a coherent sheaf. This would make the notion of vector bundle not functorial.

Comment: Functoriality is part of my question! So the accepted terminology is: A vector bundle on a scheme is a locally free $O_X$ of finite type (and maybe of constant rank)?


Comment: I am confused. In which sense can $O_X$ be not coherent? Are you schemes not noetherian? Or did you mean $f^* O_X$ not coherent?

Comment: The lack of functoriality is obvious: if you pull back the structure sheaf from $\mathop{\rm Spec}\mathbb Z$, where it is coherent to a scheme $X$, you get $\mathcal O_X$, which, as you say, might not be coherent. Vector bundles correspond to locally free sheaves of finite rank.

Comment: Dear Angelo: would you accept to read the question with my definition of vector bundle?
Dear Bugs Bunny: I've edited and added the word "necessarily" in "Suppose that $O_X$ is not *necessarily* coherent". This is (maybe a bad) way to insist that I would like conditions on the morphism $f$(=conditions on the subscheme $Z$) and not on $X$.

Comment: Workitout, if you insist on including coherence in the definition of
vector bundle (which isn't standard as Angelo points out), then
either $\mathcal{O}_Z$ should be coherent or $E$ should be $0$.
There isn't much else to say.

Comment: I am still confused: even on a non-noetherian scheme, how could the structure sheaf fail to be coherent? It should be trivial that it is coherent.

Comment: Chuck: On a non-Noetherian scheme, the definition of coherence includes more than just locally finitely generated.  Specifically, there has to be an affine cover such that on every set in the cover, any surjection to $\mathcal{F}$ from a free sheaf has finitely generated kernel.

Comment: Interesting . . . that is not the same definition as in Hartshorne. Is it generally accepted that the definition in Hartshorne is wrong? (In fact, in Example II.5.2.1, he says explicitly that the structure sheaf is always coherent).

Comment: Hartshorne defines coherent sheaves on Noetherian schemes only, in which case the two definitions agree and the structure sheaf is always coherent. (A submodule of a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is always finitely generated, so the condition on kernels becomes redundant in the Noetherian case.)

Comment: The right definition can be found in EGA for instance. Hartshorne's
book is very nice, but this one place where I think he could have
been more explicit that he was taking a short cut.

Comment: Coherence and quasi-coherence are so *orthogonal*. Names are confusing. What is the link between them?

Comment:  I'm still a little confused as to how $O_X$ could be non-finitely presented...It has an obvious finite presentation and if a module over a ring is finitely presented then it is always finitely presented right???

Comment: The "best" reference for coherence is Serre's FAC paper which isolated the concept in the 1st place, handling alg. varieties and C-analytic spaces (& many ringed spaces) in one fell swoop. In Bourbaki there's a discussion of "coh. rings", the alg. analogue of coh. sheaves (delicate generalization of noetherian rings, for which there are natural non-noetherian examples, related to formal scheme models of rigid-analytic spaces).  Dear Workitout: Quasi-coh. "sort of" a generalization of coh., hence the name (I think). The phrase "coherent topos" is *much* worse since involves no structure sheaf!

Comment: Dear Daniel: Hartshorne is wrong, wrong, wrong about def'n of coh.  It is way more subtle than finite pres. Yes, $O_X$ is finitely pres.  But that's not the def'n of coherence.  I highly recommend Serre's FAC, even just the 1st part where he works out the saga of coherence. Let me convey the idea by telling you what a coh. module $M$ is over any comm. ring $A$: $M$ is finitely gen'td and module of relations among any *finite* subset of $M$ is finitely generated.  Compare with notion of "noetherian module" from Atiyah-MacDonald! If $A$ is coh. over itself, call it coherent. *Weaker* than noeth.

Answer (score 2):

For noetherian schemes the pull-back of coherent (quasicoherent, locally free) sheaf retains that property, cf. II.5.8 in Hartshorne. The notion of coherence becomes subtle in non-noetherian case but the pull-back of locally free sheaf is locally free. However, locally free finite rank may not imply coherent.

If I understand it correctly, the question as posed has little substance. If $O_X$ is not coherent, any locally free $O_X$-module is not coherent either. Hence, $X$ has no "vector bundles"...

Comment: Also, Hartshorne uses the wrong definition of coherence.

Comment: Although Hartshorne does say (after defining coherence) something along the lines of "only for use with Noetherian schemes".  Hartshorne's definition does certainly cause substantial confusion though.

Comment: Hartshorne is not interested in non-noetherian schemes. His definition is OK in this case. Nothing I said is wrong, btw. 


Answer (score 1):

Let $f \colon X  \to Y$ be a map of locally ringed spaces, and $\mathcal{E}$ a sheaf of locally free finite rank $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules. Then $f^*\mathcal{E}$ is a sheaf of locally free finite rank $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

(If you agree that a *vector bundle* is a a sheaf of locally free finite rank $\mathcal{O}$-modules, I assume this is a fairy general answer. I guess it works also for ringed topos, but I will sketch the proof only in the space case.)

Indeed, the property of being "locally free of finite rank" is local, therefore the problem reduces to the case of a *free* finite rank sheaf, but in this case its inverse image is free because $f^*$ is an additive functor.

For the right notion of coherent sheaf I suggest to look at EGA $0_I$ 5.3 (new edition). Hartshorne's definition works well only for noetherian schemes. Also, for a discussion on the relationship between locally free sheaves (or, more generally sheaves of  $\mathcal{O}$-modules) and its associated shemes (that play the role of bundle spaces) look at EGA I, 9.4 (new edition). In the old edition I think it is somewhere in EGA II.